# isolating one column from output in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

good morning.
i am trying to avoid GUI at my job to practice powershell and one of the daily tasks i have is to check if a user was added to the right groups 
so i was using the cmdlet:

```
get-aduser $username -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof
```

and im getting a list of the groups the user is in.
but i get it like that :

```
CN=GroupName,OU=OU,OU=another OU,etc...
```

and i want it just to output the CN value 
if i would have to do that in bash i would grep it, is there any way to "grep" in powershell? or isolate the CN so it would output only that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough, just create a property in the `Select` part of your command as such:

```
get-aduser $username -Properties memberof | Select -expand memberof | select @{n='GroupName';e={$_.split(',')[0].Substring(3)}} -expand GroupName
```

That takes the Memberof property, splits it on commas, takes the first item in that split, and takes a substring of it skipping the first 3 characters. Then it assigns that value to the `GroupName` property, and expands that property.

Alternatively you can use a RegEx match, and return the matches in a `ForEach` loop.

```
get-aduser $username -Properties memberof | Select -Expand Memberof |Where{$_ -match "CN=(.*?),"} | ForEach{$Matches[1]}
```

Or parse the value in a ForEach loop using the same methods used in the first code.

```
get-aduser $username -Properties memberof | Select -expand memberof | ForEach {$_.split(',')[0].Substring(3)}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response i found the second method you suggested as the one that suits me.

Comment: Nice, that's the one I regularly use as well. I'm a fan of the RegEx matches